# Position Text depending on array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't think this is a proper question but ill ask it anyway. I have multiple paragraphs and buttons dedicated to each paragraph. When a button is clicked it adds the name of the paragraphs id into an array. if I press another button it would add that one to the array and so on. how would I then show each paragraph in the order of they are in the array.
how would i show the hidden paragraphs and put them in the order as shown in the array.

```js
var order = [];

  
  
  
  document.getElementById("par1Button").onclick = function() {

    var value = document.getElementById("par1Button").value
    
   order.push(value);
   alert(order)
  }

  document.getElementById("par2Button").onclick = function() {

   var value = document.getElementById("par2Button").value
   order.push(value);
   alert(order)
  }
  
  document.getElementById("par3Button").onclick = function() {

    var value = document.getElementById("par3Button").value
   order.push(value);
   alert(order)
  }
```

```html
<button id="par1Button" value="Par1">Par1</button>
<button id="par2Button" value="Par2">Par2</button>
<button id="par3Button" value="Par3">Par3</button>
  
<p id="par1" style="display:none;">This is text par1</p>  
<p id="par2" style="display:none;">this is the par 2</p>
<p id="par1" style="display:none;">and this is par 3</p> 
    </body>
```

Comment: your question is not clear!

Answer (score 0):

1. On every click , append the id to a hidden feild or an array with ',' or seperation symbols
2. Also on everyclick remove the button, else the same id will be added, which will be more difficult to manage...
3. finally split the hidden values and take your ids add display the paragraphs in order

its going to take some time so, please try yourself

Comment: Thanks could you explain it with the code because im not 100%

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. From my understanding I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<body>
    <button name="toggle" id="par1Button" value="par1">Add Paragraph 1</button>
    <button name="toggle" id="par2Button" value="par2">Add Paragraph 2</button>
    <p id="par1" style="display:none;">This is text par1</p>
    <p id="par2" style="display:none;">this is the par 2</p>
    <button id="show">Show Paragraphs</button>
    <script>
        var listOfParagraphs = [];
        document.getElementsByName('toggle').forEach(function(btn) {
          btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            listOfParagraphs.push(event.target.value)
          })
        })

        document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', function(e){
          if(listOfParagraphs.length >= 1) {
            listOfParagraphs.forEach(function(id) {
              document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"
            })
          }
        })

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with CSS display property. Just mapping the paragraph `textContent` accordingly is sufficient. When you click a button it will add the corresponding paragraph at the end of the array and will display the paragraphs in the order they exist in `parray` array. A second click of a button will remove the corresponding paragraph from the list.

```js
var pars = {
            par1: {id: "par1", textContent: "This is paragraph one"},
            par2: {id: "par2", textContent: "This is paragraph two"},
            par3: {id: "par3", textContent: "This is paragraph three"}
           },
    prgs = document.getElementsByTagName("p"),
 buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"),
  parray = [];

function displayPars(){
  var i = 0;
  for(var pel of prgs){
    parray[i] ? pel.textContent = parray[i].textContent
              : pel.textContent = "";
    i++;
  }
}

for(var button of buttons){
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                                     var pid = e.currentTarget.id.substr(0,4),
                                         pix = parray.findIndex(p => p.id === pid);
                                     pix !== -1 ? parray.splice(pix,1)
                                                : parray.push(pars[pid]);
                                     displayPars();
                                   });
}
```

```html
<button id="par1Button" value="Par1">Par1</button>
<button id="par2Button" value="Par2">Par2</button>
<button id="par3Button" value="Par3">Par3</button>

<p id="par1"></p>
<p id="par2"></p>
<p id="par3"></p>
```